# Unknown img.gif CloudFlare

Tags: cloudflare

Anyone know the reason why CloudFlare is injecting the following code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{(function(a){var b="https://",c="www.mywebsite.com",d="/cdn-cgi/cl/",e="img.gif",f=new a;f.src=[b,c,d,e].join("")})(Image)}catch(e){}
//]]>
</script>
```

I have other website with the same CloudFlare's configuration and i didn't notice the img.gif on the source code.

Comment: First glance I would say a tracking pixel. I am looking for a reference in their docs currently, but cannot confirm.

Comment: @David.J i agree that could be a tracking pixel but i want to avoid it... :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disabled the **ScrapeShield** app integration on the CloudFlare's dashboard and the strange code just disappeared.

Comment: Please confirm your CLoudFlare CDN functionality working fine after Disabling the ScrapeShield app ??

Comment: @VishalBharti Everything is working fine without "ScrapeShield". What's wrong?